# if/else logic using NULL

Tags: c, if-statement, null, conditional-statements

I'm not sure if I understand the conditionals using = NULL and != NULL.

Is this

```
if (somethin->example == NULL) 
{
   do task A 
   return;       
}
    
else
{
   do task B
}
```

the same as this?

```
if (somethin->example != NULL) 
{        
   do task B  
}
    
else
{  
   do task A
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent.

`==` is the inverse of `!=`. If you both invert the condition and swap the `if` and `else` blocks the two changes cancel out. These are equivalent:

```
if (a)
{
    foo();
}
else
{
    bar();
}
```

and

```
if (!a)
{
    bar();
}
else
{
    foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They are the same, the only difference is the order of comparison (is NULL vs. is not NULL)
and the order of operation blocks that go below the if statement based on the conditions written and conditions met.

```
if (x == y) {
  do(x);
} else {
  do(y);
}
```

is the same as

```
if (x != y) {
  do(y);
} else {
  do(x);
}
```

So the difference is that in the first sample we are evaluating that x is equal to y, so precedence of "equal" takes place, while the second sample we are evaluating that x is not equal to y, therefore precedence of "not equal" takes place.